# Is this charger compatible with my laptop?

Tags: laptop, charger

I just lost my laptop charger and I found another one on my house, I was wondering if it is compatible with my laptop and if you would recommend it using, the specs are the following:

ORIGINAL CHARGER (HP)
Input: 100-240 V ~ 1.4A  50-60 Hz
Output: 19.5V  2.31A
45W

REPLACEMENT CHARGER (Lenovo)
Input: 100-240 V ~ 2.5A. 50-60 Hz
Output: 20V  2A
46.08W

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Assuming the laptop plug is the same and the same polarity, it should be close enough to work as long as you don't push things.  The voltage is close enough that it shouldn't be an issue.  Its current capacity is a little less.  However, the original charger was rated to support the maximum power the laptop could need, and to charge the battery while using the laptop.  If you don't overdo things, it should be OK, especially if you charge the battery with the laptop off first, and then use it plugged in if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The voltage and amperage are pretty much the same and it's worth giving the replacement charger a shot. As long as the shape of the new charger fits snugly (not too big or small) into the receptacle of the laptop, they should be compatible.

Answer (score 0):

The BIOS on your laptop probably wouldn't like it because replacement has lower apmerage capability, but if you wouldn't load computer too much and charge empty battery in the same time, it might work. You can try, nothing dangerous while connectors are compatible (lenovo and HP has different sockets, so probably you wouldn't able just to plug it in).

BTW, HP's power supply are pretty cheap on ebay, around $6-9, just get a new one(better to look for some 90Watts, so power supply would always cover computer needs regardless loading).

Comment: Lenovo has had a few styles of connectors over the years, with the latest model using a modified USB B style connector rather than a barrel. Having used thinkpads for years, I can state that *no* thinkpad connector's the same size as those for the HP systems I have seen and used.

Comment: Yes, that is why i wrote: (lenovo and HP has different sockets, so probably you wouldn't able just to plug it in). It easy to find HP's father-connector and replace it on lenovo's PSU (well, did it myself when was out of civilization) but IMHO it is not worth it if one can wait a few days and get replacement for a few bucks.